# How to pass username/password into ambari-server sync-ldap command

Tags: shell, hadoop, ldap, ambari

I am trying to run a playbook with sync ldap command :

`ambari-server sync-ldap --all`

The thing is, after the executing of the command, it asks for username and then password.

Is there anyway to pass the username and password automatically from `echo` or using a script shell, without having to pass it manually ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with below script

```
# cat /tmp/ambari-server-sync-ldap-unattended.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect 
set timeout 20
spawn /usr/sbin/ambari-server sync-ldap --groups=/etc/ambari-server/ambari-groups.csv
expect "Enter Ambari Admin login:" { send "admin\n" }
expect "Enter Ambari Admin password:" { send "notTheRealPasswordOfCourse\n" }
interact
```

Comment: I ried the curl sync and it works, than you so much

Comment: Please summarize the content of the link, to avoid to be a "link-only" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

An simple example is to use the following script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
ambari-server sync-ldap --all

# wait until the prompt shows "enter username". Change this to adapt to your application.
expect "enter username"
send "your_username\r"

# wait until the prompt shows "password: ". Change this to adapt to your application.
expect "password: "
send "yourPAssWoRD\r"


interact
```

**Disclaimer**: I have never used `ambari-server` command before.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, it reads only the 'ambari-server sync-ldap --all' command, and then it says enter username..

Comment: I already adapted it, like expect "Enter Ambari Admin login:", but the script doesn't reach the next step, it runs the first command only, after that it says command not found (meaning he is not able to pass the expect command..)

Comment: @imel Do you have `expect` installed? `sudo apt install expect`

Comment: my bad, I just found out I didn't have the expect. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Another question, can't I use something else other than expect ? because I am not alowed to install expect in the main server !

Comment: @imel If it is necessary, you can compile expect from [source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/files/) and build the executable from it. Or talk to your admin and get it installed on the server.

Comment: I used a curl command and it works perfectly, so no need for expect command. Thanks for your answer though